# Was 司马懿 a crossdresser?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading an abridged version of 三国演义。(I don't think I could read the original, too difficult for me.)

（诸葛亮）故意激怒司马懿，派人送了一套女人的衣服，并辱骂他像女人一样，缩头不战。司马懿心里恼怒，但却穿上衣服，文使者：“诸葛亮忙吗？吃饭睡觉情况怎么样？”

Did 司马懿 put on women's clothes to meet 诸葛亮's envoy? Or is this just a bad book?

Answer (score 3):

> Did 司马懿 put on women's clothes to meet 诸葛亮's envoy?

I don't think 司马懿 really put on the clothes.

From the [original](http://www.shicimingju.com/book/sanguoyanyi/103.html):

(emphasis mine)

> 且说孔明自引一军屯于五丈原，累令人搦战，魏兵只不出。孔明乃取巾帼并妇人缟素之服，盛于大盒之内，修书一封，遣人送至魏寨。诸将不敢隐蔽，引来使入见司马懿。懿对众启盒视之，内有巾帼妇人之衣，并书一封。懿拆视其书，略曰：“仲达既为大将，统领中原之众，不思披坚执锐，以决雌雄，乃甘窟守土巢，谨避刀箭，与妇人又何异哉！今遣人送巾帼素衣至，如不出战，可再拜而受之。倘耻心未泯，犹有男子胸襟，早与批回，依期赴敌。”司马懿看毕，心中大怒，乃佯笑曰：“孔明视我为妇人耶！”即**受之**，令重待来使。

受之 only means 司马懿 received / took in / accepted the clothes.

[Here](http://novel.tingroom.com/html/book/show/179/6328.html)'s an English version:

(emphasis mine)

> Then he confirmed the order to remain strictly on the defensive till
>   some change of circumstances on the part of the enemy should promise
>   advantage.
>
> After his army had settled into camp on the Wuzhang Hills, Zhuge Liang
>   continued his attempts to provoke a battle. Day after day, parties
>   went to challenge the army of Wei, but they resisted all provocation.
>
> One day Zhuge Liang put a dress made of deer hide in a box, which he
>   sent, with a letter, to his rival. The insult could not be concealed,
>   so the generals led the bearer of the box to their chief. Sima Yi
>   opened the box and saw the deer hide dress. Then he opened the letter,
>   which read something like this:
>
> "Friend Sima Yi, although you are a Commander-in-Chief and lead the
>   armies of the Middle Land, you seem but little disposed to display the
>   firmness and valor that would render a contest decisive. Instead, you
>   have prepared a comfortable lair where you are safe from the keen edge
>   of the sword. Are you not very like a deer? Wherefore I send the
>   bearer with a suitable gift, and you will humbly accept it and the
>   humiliation, unless, indeed, you finally decide to come out and fight
>   like a warrior. If you are not entirely indifferent to shame, if you
>   retain any of the feelings of a tiger, you will send this back to me
>   and come out and give battle."
>
> Sima Yi, although inwardly raging, pretended to take it all as a joke
>   and smiled.
>
> "So he regards me as a deer," said he.
>
> **He accepted the gift** and treated the messenger well.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely not.

三国演义 is a novel, therefore the stories in 三国演义 are not nessecarily fact. And as described in @songyuanyao's answer, 三国演义 does not say that 司马懿 put on the cloths.

A relevant Story in [晋书](http://www.guoxue.com/shibu/24shi/jinshu/jinshu_001.htm) (History of the Jin Dynasty) reads as following:

```
亮数挑战，帝不出，因遗帝巾帼妇人之饰。帝怒，表请决战，天子不许，乃遣骨鲠臣卫尉辛毗杖节为军师以制之。
```

[诸葛亮 challenged 司马懿 to fight for multiple times, but 司马懿 did not respond. Therefore 诸葛亮 send a set of women's clothes to 司马懿 (to irritate him). 司马懿 was angry, and he wrote a letter to the king asking for permission to fight, but the king did not allow. The king appointed 辛毗 as 司马懿's military advisor to control him.]

The book you read may not be a bad book, but a little more fictional. Some TV shows also features the similar story where 司马懿 puts on the women's cloth and even shows off in front of 诸葛亮。

Answer (score 1):

我理解他穿上那件诸葛亮送的女人衣服，他是想像使者传递一个信息: "我知道你是有意激怒我，从而达到让我出战的目的。 但我不会上你的当，我已经识破了你的计谋。"

Maybe, more context would help to understand it more clearly.